# Data driven asp.net mvc layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-views, asp.net-mvc-layout

I have a controller action:

```
 public ActionResult Sub(int id)
    {
      SubPage_Table subpage_table = db.SubPage_Table.Single(s => s.PageID == id);
        if (subpage_table == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(subpage_table);
    }
```

And a View:

```
@model Name.Models.DB.SubPage_Table
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.PageContent))
```

But my layout needs to be strongly typed:

```
@model IEnumerable<Name.Models.DB.SubPage_Table> 
          @foreach (var item in Model)
          {@: <li> @Html.ActionLink((item.PageTitle), "Sub", new { id = item.PageID })</li>
```

}

How do I populate my view and Layout with data?

Comment: You are going to assume that every single page you ever create with that layout in your application needs `IEnumerable<Name.Models.DB.SubPage_Table>`?  That seems very unrealistic.

Comment: Hm, I wanted to... Unless You know how to create links like @Html.ActionLink((item.PageTitle), "Sub", new { id = item.PageID }
 not using Ienumerable?
Beacuse for now I create using foreach loop

Comment: So your real question sounds like *how do I retrieve data for my layouts*?

Comment: Hm, Lokoks like you are right. 
I tried with List<SubPage_Table> subpage_table =db.SubPage_Table.Where(s => s.PageID == id).ToList();
in controller but ewentually as a result in  new { id = item.PageID } Pages I got only one link displaying instead of all. (only the current one was displayed so if I went to the SubPage "Test" then in Menu only "Test" was displayed, instead of "test2" , "test3" etc...

Comment: I've updated your question to talk about the relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

Here is on of the better options:

Create a partial view with your data-driven information

```
public LayoutController
{
  public ActionResult CreateMenu()
  {
    var model = db.getmenudata();

    return PartialView(model);
  }
}
```

Then your Layout/Createmenu.cshtml creates just the html that is data driven.

In your _Layout.cshtml:

```
<html>
... etc

@Html.RenderAction("Createmenu", "layout");

... etc

@RenderBody();


... etc
</html>
```